# Binded Textarea truncates value in Blazor WASM if it contains HTML code

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I'm using .NET 6 and Blazor WASM. When I paste to textarea normal text, no matter how long or short, it works fine and shows up in variable. However if I paste HTML source code from website (for example this site, or any other), it seems to truncate it from middle if it's longer than thousands of characters. It takes X amount of characters from beginning and end, in the middle it has `…`. The truncated string is usually around 1000-1200 characters.

I tried extracting the value from textarea-element with vanilla js and it worked completely fine.

NOTE! This did work ~2-3 months ago, I just suddenly noticed it stopped working. I have deployed code similar to this, but on different file. I have not manually updated anything in framework or editor (Visual Studio 2022)

So I have simple code that is something like this:

```
<form>
    <label for="pasteHtml">Paste HTML code here</label>
    <textarea @bind="pastedHtml" id="pasteHtml" rows="3"></textarea>
</form>
<button @onclick="ParseHtml"> Parse HTML</button>
```

```
@code {
    // This is where I have the problem, pastedHtml value is truncated if it contains HTML code..
    private string pastedHtml= "";

    private void ParseHtml()
    {
        // Code... etc
```

Comment: What you have created here is not a question - it is more like a bug issue - those should be posted on the aspnetcore GitHub repo.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thanks for suggestion, I will try that too. I kinda thought it is just some kind of new protection against injecting code in forms or something.. Appreciate

Comment: Are you certain that the source value was not truncated before being placed on the clipboard?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Actually after trying Vikman's examples, I see the problem actually is not that textarea bind truncates it, but rather Visual Studio value inspecting shows it truncated, and for some reason HtmlAgilityPack also reads the truncated version, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with textarea and InputTextArea.

**InputTextArea Example:**

```cshtml
@page "/test"

<EditForm EditContext="@_editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleOnValidSubmit">

    <div class="form-group row m-3">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Html Code:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <InputTextArea class="form-control" @bind-Value="sampleCode.HtmlCode" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row m-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<div class="row m-3">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        HTML code length: @length
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private int length;
    private SampleCode sampleCode = new SampleCode();
    private EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(sampleCode);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public void HandleOnValidSubmit()
    {
        this.length = sampleCode.HtmlCode.Length;
        Console.WriteLine($"HTML code length: {sampleCode.HtmlCode.Length}");
    }

    public class SampleCode
    {
        public string HtmlCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: InputTextArea example output]

**textarea Example:**

```html
@page "/test"

<div class="form-group row mb-3">
    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Html Code:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" @oninput="OnInput"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div>HTML code length: @length</div>

@code {
    private int length;

    void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        this.length = args.Value.ToString().Length;
    }
}
```

[image: textarea example output]

Comment: Thank you for code examples, they actually showed me that the code can handle and even print the HTML code with no problems, but the problem seems to appear in Visual Studio when inspecting the value while debugging.. Also the problem somehow carries over when using HtmlAgilityPack to handle the data, still unsure what is the problematic part. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For what purpose are you using the HtmlAgilityPack library? Are you open to trying other libraries?

Comment: I am extracting information from the HTML source code. I save the HTML source code as HtmlDocument with HtmlAgilityPack so I can select nodes and save information for analyzing.